# reason: Material version mismatch. Expected 3 but received 4

Tags: java, android, sceneform

I created sfb files with:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.15.0'
```

but I want to use them inside another android project:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.15.0'
```

I got this error message:

```
2022-04-16 15:58:57.728 8107-8753/com.****.app E/ACameraMetadata: getConstEntry: cannot find metadata tag 65578
2022-04-16 15:58:58.129 8107-8107/com.****.app E/Filament: Panic
    in filament::Material *filament::Material::Builder::build(filament::Engine &):86
    reason: Material version mismatch. Expected 3 but received 4.
2022-04-16 15:58:58.129 8107-8107/com.****.app E/Filament: --------- beginning of crash
2022-04-16 15:58:58.129 8107-8107/com.****.app A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 8107 (ashamcarpet.app), pid 8107 (ashamcarpet.app)
2022-04-16 15:58:58.328 8107-8753/com.****.app E/native: E0416 15:58:58.328268    8753 camera_image_stream.cc:231] Camera Image Stream failed to dequeue Image from ImageReader. status=UNAVAILABLE: AImageReader_acquireLatestImage [type.googleapis.com/util.ErrorSpacePayload='ImageReaderStatusErrorSpaceClass::AMEDIA_IMGREADER_NO_BUFFER_AVAILABLE']
    === Source Location Trace: === 
    third_party/arcore/ar/camera/android/imagereader_status_error_space.cc:112
    third_party/arcore/ar/camera/android/imagereader_ndk_wrapper.cc:240
     acquired_image_count=9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of this error downgrade Ar Sceneform plugin version to:

```
classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.11.0'
```